# Password protect directory in Apache

Tags: apache

I want to set password for one directory using Apache server so that only authorized persons can access to the directory. I have created .htpasswd file inside the directory. And it contains one line

```
username:$apr1$5H33Pfw6$WApVs3KlrU7QgBqYrFgeW.
```

password is "password". And my Directory Preferences are

```
<Directory />
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Example Repository"
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

When accessing the directory from browser it asks for username and password. After entering username and password request fails. Http Request error code is 403. What could be the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html

Syntax: AuthUserFile file-path

File-path is the path to the user file. If it is not absolute, it is treated as relative to the ServerRoot.

Comment: I have tried with full path also. But No success. AuthUserFile C:/Repositories/Test.git/.htpasswd

Comment: Should I input hashed password.

Comment: You said you get HTTP error code 403. Which is by Wiki: Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference. So my guess is, that somewhere else in your configuration anything is wrong.

Comment: OK Thanks. Even I think so. Because browser will give different outputs for wrong and correct password. So I think Something went wrong with some other settings. If I put "Allow from all" inside <Directory /> then it will work fine.

Comment: I have added Allow from all" inside <Directory />. Now it works fine for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the complete path to your .htpasswd file. Try with

```
AuthUserFile /complete/passwd/file/path/.htpasswd
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried with full path also. But No success. 

AuthUserFile C:/Repositories/Test.git/.htpasswd

Comment: Should I input hashed password.

Comment: Try with double quotes: AuthUserFile "C:/Repositories/Test.git/.htpasswd"